# sqlalchemy invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run the following code but I got a `sqlalchemy invalid literal for int() with base 10` error.

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://:127.0.0.1:5432/lecture03")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
for flight in flights:
    print("{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.",format(flight.origin,flight.destination,flight.duration))

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: I think there's one colon `:` too many in your connection string. Should be `postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/lecture03`

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Here's the output when i delete.

Comment: So the connection string was invalid. Password is missing is a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one colon too many in your connection string. If you also need to provide credentials, prepend them with `@` ([docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html)):

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/lecture03")
```

Comment: i assigned username and password and it works. thanks a lot.